# Duplicate items in a doubly linked list

Tags: c#, list, linked-list, duplicates, doubly-linked-list

I need to duplicate each element of a doubly-linked list containing at least one even digit.

```
Input: 12, 19, 22, 34, 77, 55.
Output: 12, 12, 19, 22, 22, 34, 34, 77, 55
```

How can I do it using C#?

Comment: Your question needs some clarification. Not sure what it has to do with linked lists? What have you tried so far, can you include some example code? You say you need to "duplicate digits", but your example seems to indicate you want to duplicate the entire entry if any even digits show up in that entry. For example you duplicate the entire "34" entry seemingly because it contains a "4".

Comment: Tip: You can convert the number into a string (`number.ToString()`) and then check every character in it OR you can use the integer division `/` and modulo operator `%` to get the digits in a loop (requires more reflection).

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't specified the type of data I'm going to give you a generic solution:

```
public List<T> DuplicateListElements(List<T> list)
        {
            List<T> res = new List<T>();
            foreach (T t in list)
            {
                res.Add(t);

                if(t%2 == 0)
                   res.Add(t);
            }
            return res;
        }
```

And you use it like this:

```
List<T> myDuplicateList = DuplicateListElements(inputList);
```

You should change the `T` in the code for the datatype that can use the operator `%`, or create a generic class `T` and work around it.

This answer also may assumes that you are using the data structure `List<>`.

Next time try to clarify your question for a more accurate answer.